# Habilitar controles após efetuar login

Tags: c#, winforms

Ola...então preciso de uma ajuda

Estou precisando fazer com que após efectuar o login, na tela de login quando clicar no botão confirmar, os campos do MDI Principal sejam habilitados (menustrip), ou seja quando a aplicação e carregada , o form_load chama o form de login para inserir o nome de usuário e senha. após autenticado, essa tela de login fecha e o MDI principal habilita os menus. detalhe importante é que ambos são carregados juntos, o Form MDI e o form login para que o usuário faça a autenticação no sistema.

```
    //Form Pai - MDI
    private void MDIPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login login = new Login();

        login.MdiParent = this;

        menuStrip1.Enabled = false;

        login.Show();
    }

    public void habilitarControlers(bool valor)
    {
        menuStrip1.Refresh();
        menuStrip1.Enabled = valor;

    }


    // Form Filho - Login
    public delegate void definirValortextoRechamada(bool valor);

    public definirValortextoRechamada definirValorTexto;

    MDIPrincipal pai;

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pai = new MDIPrincipal();

        definirValorTexto += new definirValortextoRechamada(pai.habilitarControlers);

    }

    private void btnConfirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        definirValorTexto(true);

        Close();


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde Leo Barbosa, pelo que entendi são dois Formularios diferentes correto?
Qual deles está para iniciar no Startup?

Uma tentativa a ser feita é colocar o MDI principal como principal no startup e nele chamar a tela de Login com o MDI principal escondido.
Após liberação do Login, fecharia o formulário de Login e adicionaria um visible true no MDI Principal.

Tenta essa ideia e da um retorno.

Abraços.

Comment: Dae Luiz, desculpe pela demora em responder...eu entendi a sua logica porém não é a que eu quero fazer...no caso dos forms devem ser carregados juntos, tanto o MDI quanto o de login porém o menustrip do MDI deve ficar desabilitado enquanto a autenticação do usuário não for feita.

Comment: Exatamente, você irá carregar os dois, mas só vai tornar visível o MDI após concluir as etapas no formulário do Login, porem o MDI é o startup, então você terá que chamar o login depois de iniciar ele. Acho que é uma alternativa.

Conseguiu outra lógica? se sim dividi com a gente.
Abraços.